# How to get user groups or roles from Identity Aware Proxy in a MERN stack app

Tags: google-cloud-platform, identity-aware-proxy

I have a use case where I have 2 apps:

- React SPA frontend, running on web.myportal.example
- Node Express backend, exposing a REST api on api.myportal.example

Both apps are deployed into `GCP Compute Engine` and are accessible from the Internet. I was able to configure IAP to prevent unauthorized access. I can specify a list of email accounts that are allowed to use the UI and API.

What I need is **autorization** capability from GCP IAP. Does it have one?
Simple example - some of the API endpoints should only be accessible to folks with a specific group/role membership. How can I extract that from IAP? The only thing IAP leaves me is a `GCP_IAAP_AUTH_TOKEN` cookie, which I cant even use due to it's definition.

Comment: Do you want different permissions according to who accessed the site ? Are they have to be different for front and backend ?

Comment: Yes, different permissions for different users based on their google roles or groups in google. Both UI and API will need to differentiate - so, yes, different permissions on both applications.

Answer (score 1):

You may try to put an LB in front of each service (one for API, another for an APP) and configure IAP to use them and [grant access accordingly](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/concepts-overview#how_iap_works).

> When an application or resource is protected by IAP, it can only be
> accessed through the proxy by members, also known as users, who have
> the correct Identity and Access Management (IAM) role. When you grant
> a user access to an application or resource by IAP, they're subject to
> the fine-grained access controls implemented by the product in use
> without requiring a VPN. When a user tries to access a IAP-secured
> resource, IAP performs authentication and authorization checks.

But it's not possible to configure IAP to grant different access-level to an API methods based on who logged in. It doesn't look like at allows such fine-grained [authorisation](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/concepts-overview#authorization) management - only you get access or no;

> After authentication, IAP applies the relevant IAM policy to check if
> the user is authorized to access the requested resource. If the user
> has the IAP-secured Web App User role on the Cloud Console project
> where the resource exists, they're authorized to access the
> application.